# CUDA output variable are always 0

Tags: c, linux, cuda, gpu, nvidia

I have made a serial version for a code to calculate a histogram and I know the algorithm works. The problem is that when I do it in CUDA, the only thing I get back as a results are all 0. I can copy the input array dev_x into the output variable h, and I am able to see the input values of x.

The input data is a list of x and y positions with a corresponding color (int from 1 to 5)

The arguments are the input file name, output file name, cellWidth and cellHeight, where
cellWidth and cellHeight is the number of regions the input is divided in. A 1000000 X 1000000 array is divided into 1000 X 1000 regions. I need to calculate the number of occurrences of each color in each region.

Comment: add [proper cuda error checking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) to your code, and you'll likely get an idea of where things are going wrong.

Comment: In addition to the error checking point, it would be good if your code was self contained. Right now it requires a file and an understanding of the required command line arguments and values that nobody but you has access to. I can't/don't know how to run your program, so I can't see what it does or use any of the standard diagnostic tools to find what might be going wrong. Without that, I fail to see how anyone can actually answer this question. Vote to close.

Comment: @RobertCrovella - I will add error checking as soon as I get home tonight. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @talonmies - I added a description of the input arguments and input file.

Comment: @dead_jake: Are you telling me that to run your program I should just make my own input text file with a few billion lines in it and run your code? Does that seem reasonable to you?

Comment: @talonmies - The size of the array does not really matter. I can provide a test input file later tonight.

Comment: Are you seriously telling me you want me to download a **150Mb** text file to run your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two gigantic, basic problems in this code, neither of which has anything to do with CUDA:

```
histSize = sizeof(unsigned int) * xMax/cellWidth * yMax/cellHeight * numColors;

//....

 h = (unsigned int*) malloc(histSize);

//.....

for(i=0; i<histSize; i++)
    h[i]=0; // <-- buffer oveflow
```

which is probably killing the program before it ever even gets to launch the kernel, and:

```
cudaMalloc( (void**) &dev_h, histSize );

// .......

cudaMemcpy(dev_h, h, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); // buffer overflow
```

which would kill the CUDA context if the program ever got that far.

These are *elementary* mistakes and you haven't detected them because your only usage case is apparently a program which attempts to process a 150Mb input file and emit a large histogram from it, and your only method of detecting errors is looking at a file containing that histogram. That is a completely insane way to develop and debug code. If you had done any of the following:

1. Hardcoded a trivially small test case you already knew the answers for
2. Added CUDA API error checking
3. Run valgrind
4. Used cuda-memcheck
5. Used a host debugger
6. ran nvprof

you probably would have instantly detected the problems (there might well be more but I don't care enough to look for them, that is your job), and this Stack Overflow question wouldn't exist.